# How can we customize "View Item" form after using InfoPath?

Tags: list, infopath, view

I created a InfoPath form, and when I click on "New Item" I am able to see the nice form. 
However, when the user clicks "View Item" the form has sections that I would like to remove/hide.

Is there a way of customizing this "View Item" form?

Preferably I would like to achieve this customization using InfoPath.

Thank you for reading.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post that walks you through the process: http://blog.libinuko.com/2010/03/21/sharepoint-2010-howto-start-customize-list-form-neweditview-using-infopath-designer-2010/

Example:
[image]